# IF time is after 4 PM then show this cell, if false show this cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trading stocks and I want to show extended hours price of a stock if the time is 4:00PM or higher. During the hours before 4pm I want to just show the price. I currently have this formula `=IF(TODAY()>DATEVALUE("16:00"),G149.[Price (Extended hours)],G149.Price)` but it is not functioning properly. If it's after 4pm it will show the extended price of a stock but when its before 4pm I am getting `#FIELD!`. Can someone help me come up with the proper formula?

Comment: G149.Price is not a correct reference to a sheet and cell in excel.

Comment: also need to chk : `TODAY()>DATEVALUE("16:00")` part,the evaluation will always be true.

Comment: the solution for that part is : `NOW()>(TODAY()+TIME(16,0,0))`